# Initialze a member of a C++ templated class only for specific type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Suppose I have a templated class like this:

```
template <typename C>
class ValArray
{
    ValArray() = default;
    ValArray(const ValArray&) = delete;

    C& operator[](size_t pos) { return _values[pos]; }
  ...
private:
    std::array<C, ARRAY_SIZE> _values;
};
```

This is instantiated with lots of different types.  What I would like to do is initialize `_values` *only* for type `bool` but not for other types.  So, if I create `ValArray<bool> val` then I want all elements to be `false`, for example:

```cpp
std::array<bool, ARRAY_SIZE> _values = {false};
```

But for any other type, I don't want to initialize `_values` at all.

Is there some template magic I haven't been able to find that will allow this?  I'm hoping to not have to create a separate class for this, as this would cascade to many other places where I'd have to create specializations.

Comment: You only want to initialize bools, you might get away with assignment instead of initialization, since there's no practical difference.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand that comment.  What I want is that when I instantiate an instance of this template with <bool>, the array values are initialized.  When I instantiate this template with any type other than bool, I don't want the array values initialized at all (they should be left as uninitialized memory and no ctor/dtor is invoked for each element of the array).

Comment: @MadScientist "*I don't want the array values initialized at all  (they should be left as uninitialized memory and no ctor/dtor is invoked for each element of the array)*" - well, sorry to say, but that is simply not how arrays work when the element type has a constructor/destructor defined. To get around that, you would have to create a byte array instead and then `placement-new`/destroy the individual elements manually as needed. What are you REALLY trying to accomplish? This sounds like a possible [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: @RemyLebeau hmm, I believe there was a boost "array" container like that, there is no `std::` analog today?

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke: you're right: I realize the default ctor will be run for each element.  In particular what I want is that if I use a POD, it should not be initialized to any particular value.  But for bool, I want the array elements to be initialized.

Comment: You need to specialise just `ValArray` for `bool`. No cascading to any other place.

Comment: *"Sorry but I didn't understand that comment."* I meant conditionally assigning to the array in constructor body, something like Remy Labeau suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++17 and later, you can use `if constexpr` inside the constructor to assign the array elements, eg:

```
template <typename C>
class ValArray
{
public:
    ValArray() {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<C, bool>) {
            _values.fill(false);
        }
    }

    ...

private:
    std::array<C, ARRAY_SIZE> _values;
};
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/gN5iK8_3x)

If `C` is `bool`, the constructor will be compiled as:

`ValArray() { _values.fill(false); }`

Otherwise it will be compiled as:

`ValArray() {}`

Prior to C++17, you can accomplish the same thing using SFINAE via `std::enable_if`, eg:

```
template <typename C>
class ValArray
{
public:
    template<typename T = C, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, bool>::value, int>::type = 0>
    ValArray() { _values.fill(false); }

    template<typename T = C, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, bool>::value, int>::type = 0>
    ValArray() { }
    
    // ...

private:
    std::array<C, ARRAY_SIZE> _values;
};
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/ZyB81p)

Comment: Hah!  This is almost identical to @ildjarn's deleted answer below except they had a slight incorrectness in the `std::enable_if<>`.

Comment: This worked in my situation, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Among ways HOW this can be done you can simply add a specialization for a class member after  declaration you already have for this case, something like this:

```
template<> 
constexpr ValArray<bool>::ValArray() noexcept : _values({false}) {};
```

Because ctor was defaulted explicitly that should be moved and  exception specifier should be consistent across all constructors:

```
template <typename C>
class ValArray
{
public:
    ValArray() noexcept;
    ValArray(const ValArray&) = delete;

    C& operator[](size_t pos) { return _values[pos]; }

private:
    std::array<C, ARRAY_SIZE> _values;
};

template<typename C>  ValArray<C>::ValArray() noexcept = default;
template<>  ValArray<bool>::ValArray() noexcept : _values({false}) {};
```

Similar constructs for specialization are available in very early version of C++, no SFINAE  or `if constexpr` is required in this case.

Comment: Clever, to use the noexcept to get a different constructor signature.  However although this compiles with GCC, it fails to compile with clang (_error: definition of explicitly defaulted default constructor_).  Also, while it does compile it doesn't seem to do the right thing even in GCC: this new ctor is not chosen when I use `ValArray<bool> foo` and I get back random results.  Maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: @MadScientist aaah, that's what they changed about explicitly default ones, sorry was writing that in travel, so it was by seat of pants. Just added an extra step

Comment: @MadScientist I have only question , why didn't you inherited ValArray from std::array privately and didn't promote members of `std::array` you wanted to public? That kind of feels natural.  Explicitly  removing relation to type?

Comment: There are other things in this class, that's just a cut-down example.  I'm not sure the full class is appropriately inherited from std::array.  But, something to consider for sure.